# How to open the bootstrap nav menu on hover and focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to open the nav bar menu, on hover as well as focus. this is what I tried:
But on hover it is working fine, but on focus the menu list should open.

As screen readers uses key board tab button, I need to open the menu list, like the same way it is opening on hover.

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".dropdown").hover(            
        function() {
            $('.dropdown-menu', this).stop( true, true ).slideDown("fast");
            $(this).toggleClass('open');        
        },
        function() {
            $('.dropdown-menu', this).stop( true, true ).slideUp("fast");
            $(this).toggleClass('open');       
        }
    ).focus(function() {
            $('.dropdown-menu', this).stop( true, true ).slideDown("fast");
            $(this).toggleClass('open');        
        },
        function() {
            $('.dropdown-menu', this).stop( true, true ).slideUp("fast");
            $(this).toggleClass('open');       
        }
    )
});
```

Fiddle Link:
[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/kyn69prm/4/)

Comment: What do you mean by "focus"? Focus on what?

Comment: For screen readers when ever I press the keyboard tab button.

Answer (score 0):

`jQuery.focus` does not take 2 handlers like `hover` does. It takes only 1 handler function. Also, focus event works across the browsers for form and anchor elements. You are trying to use it on a list item. It may not work consistently.

However, if you add `tabindex` property to your element, focus event will work on most of the latest browsers.

Here is an example:

```js
$('.dropdown').focus(function(){
  alert('Focus event works!');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input tabindex="1" placeholder="Move focus with TAB" />
<ul>
  <li class="dropdown" tabindex="2">Works</li>
  <li class="dropdown">Does not work, not focused.</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It works but when the focus is out how do I close the child menu list. It is not closing

Comment: Use `.blur()` event handler.

Comment: Can't you have a variable that state if it's opened or not and interecept the tab key to close it if it was opened and currently focused ?